# How can I change the group of a file when executing in a Travis CI build?

Tags: travis-ci

I've got a Python Travis CI build and a Python unit test executes attempts to change the group of a file on the filesystem. The file was previously created by the unit test, so the user executing the test owns the file.

I'm able to start a sub-shell in which I *can* run chgrp commands (per [the Travis guidelines](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Group-membership)), but unfortunately, this screws up the virtualenv set up for my specific Python version (and who knows what else).

**How to replicate** (in Travis CI script):

```
language: python
sudo: true

python:
    - "3.4"
    - "3.5"

before_install:
    - sudo apt-get -qq update
    - sudo gpasswd -a $USER fuse

script:
    - touch testfile
    - chgrp fuse testfile | echo 0 # this does not work - bad
    - sudo -E su $USER -c "chgrp fuse testfile" # the sudo / su wrapper is required per Travis instructions, see link above - good
    - python --version # reports 3.4 or 3.5 - good
    - sudo -E su $USER -c "python --version" # always reports 2.7 - bad
    - sudo -E su $USER -c "python --version" # always reports 3.2 - bad
```

As I've commented in the block above, running a command which attempts to change the group of the `testfile` (which is what my unit test code is doing) only works when wrapped with `sudo -E su $USER -c`.

Unfortunately, when I do this, I lose the ability to access python 3.4 and 3.5 in those script phases (which I've specified above) in the virtualenv that Travis has set up for me.

Any idea how I can achieve both of my goals? (allowing chgrp from the `travis` non-root user while simultaneously not mucking with the virtualenv or the `python` on the path?

Comment: Try adding `sudo: required` to the top of your `.travis.yml`

Comment: Yep, I already have `sudo: required` in the Travis configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new group, you have to log out and log in again to be able to use chgrp.

Using sudo is a way around this behavior. Since you're already using it for groupadd and usermod, I suggest changing the last line to `sudo chgrp newtravisgroup newfile`.

You can also use `su` to create a new login shell where newtravisgroup will be available but using sudo as mentioned above is the simplest way.

Edit:

When you use `su` PATH is reset. That's the reason python reverts back to the system python. You can activate the virtualenv again before running your test.

`sudo -E su $USER -c "source $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate; python --version"`

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for me - the runtime code that the unit test is executing is running as a non-root user, so this doesn't help. I should note that this code works correctly *outside* of travis ci, just not *within* the travis CI environment.

Comment: I edited my answer to add the line that activates virtualenv to get the expected python version.